# Injecting Mockito mocks into a Spring bean

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, junit, annotations, mockito

I would like to inject a Mockito mock object into a Spring (3+) bean for the purposes of unit testing with JUnit. My bean dependencies are currently injected by using the `@Autowired` annotation on private member fields.

I have considered using `ReflectionTestUtils.setField` but the bean instance that I wish to inject is actually a proxy and hence does not declare the private member fields of the target class. I do not wish to create a public setter to the dependency as I will then be modifying my interface purely for the purposes of testing.

I have followed some [advice](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=58444&page=1) given by the Spring community but the mock does not get created and the auto-wiring fails:

```
<bean id="dao" class="org.mockito.Mockito" factory-method="mock">
    <constructor-arg value="com.package.Dao" />
</bean>
```

The error I currently encounter is as follows:

```
...
Caused by: org...NoSuchBeanDefinitionException:
    No matching bean of type [com.package.Dao] found for dependency:
    expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency.
    Dependency annotations: {
        @org...Autowired(required=true),
        @org...Qualifier(value=dao)
    }
at org...DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(D...y.java:901)
at org...DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(D...y.java:770)
```

If I set the `constructor-arg` value to something invalid no error occurs when starting the application context.

Comment: Please take a look at this tiny little creature:
https://bitbucket.org/kubek2k/springockito/wiki/Home

Comment: This is a very clean approach - I like it!

Comment: You had me at Springockito-annotations.

Comment: Forget all the rest, `springockito-annotations` is something you want to use. The nice thing is that you can have a non-complete XML configuration (omit the mocks) and annotations will fill in the blanks (the mocks). Then just `@Autowire` everything.

Comment: Sadly, Springockito doesn't let you easily grab the `WebApplicationContext` (you might do this if you're writing an integration test with `@WebAppConfiguation`), as documented by tihs issue: https://bitbucket.org/kubek2k/springockito/issue/12/plz-give-another-contextloader-that
You've probably just got to call the `mock()` method yourself.

Comment: Beware of https://bitbucket.org/kubek2k/springockito/issue/37/spring-test-context-caching-confuses

Comment: For those using spring 4.*,  as of Jan 2015 this does not appear to be working with latest spring mockito version and the project appears to be inactive.

Comment: @kubek2k: your links are broken.. could you please update it?

Answer (score 134):

The best way is:

```
<bean id="dao" class="org.mockito.Mockito" factory-method="mock"> 
    <constructor-arg value="com.package.Dao" /> 
</bean>
```

**Update**
In the context file this mock must be listed before any autowired field depending on it is declared.

Comment: I get an error: "Error creating bean with name 'mockito': bean definition is abstract"

Comment: @amra: spring dosn't infer the type of the object returned in this case... http://stackoverflow.com/q/6976421/306488

Comment: Don't know why this answer is upvoted so much, the resulting bean cannot be autowired because it has the wrong type.

Comment: It can be autowired if it is listed first in the context file (before any autowired fields that would depend on it are declared.)

Comment: Agree with @Ryan, it works if the mock bean is defined before the dependent bean. I think this is because Spring unable to guess what the type of the mocked bean would be, hence unless it is actually there, Spring unable to determine that the mock has to be created beforehand

Comment: Yup, as @Ryan said, works for us, when the mock bean is configured at the top of the context file (after any imports).

Comment: As of spring 3.2, the order of the beans no longer matters.  See the section entitled "Generic Factory Methods" in this blog post: http://spring.io/blog/2012/11/07/spring-framework-3-2-rc1-new-testing-features/

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16833063/spring-context-dirty-after-each-integration-test about spring 3.2 remedy.

Comment: The question says that the OP has tried this and it didn't work.  There's no point in having an answer that just repeats what the OP is already doing.  Did over 100 upvoters bother to read the question?

Comment: This doesn't work for me... I get: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException

Comment: I want to have a spy not mock. Can I do this in xml config?

Comment: Use factory-method="spy".

Answer (score 118):

```
@InjectMocks
private MyTestObject testObject;

@Mock
private MyDependentObject mockedObject;

@Before
public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}
```

This will inject any mocked objects into the test class. In this case it will inject mockedObject into the testObject. This was mentioned above but here is the code.

Comment: How do I stub a particular method of `mockedObject`?

Comment: @Teinacher 
when(mockedObject.execute).thenReturn(objToReturn); You can put that either in the before method or inside your test method.

Comment: FYI: This approach won't work, if i want partial Autowiring and partial mocking in MyTestObject.

Comment: This is exactly the type of solution I was looking for.  Very simple and elegant, and gets the job done.  Not sure why there aren't more up votes.

Comment: I don't know why this isn't voted higher.  If I see any more answers containing XML I'm going to hurl.

Comment: Worth adding, if you want to do partial Autowiring and partial mocking (as mentioned by @techastute), you could just drop the "@Injectmocks" annotation and inject your dependencies (mocked or otherwise) via a constructor. You would of course have to annotate the new constructor with "@Autowired".

Comment: Why don't you use `Mockito.spy(...)` on this `mockedObject` instead? And then use `when(mockedObject.execute).thenReturn(objToReturn)` or `doReturn(objToReturn).when(mockedObject).execute()`. Second one don't invoke real method. You can check also `Mockito.doCallRealMethod()` documentation

Comment: If you want partial autowiring, use spy instead.

Answer (score 65):

I have a very simple solution using Spring Java Config and Mockito:

```
@Configuration
public class TestConfig {

    @Mock BeanA beanA;
    @Mock BeanB beanB;

    public TestConfig() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this); //This is a key
    }

    //You basically generate getters and add @Bean annotation everywhere
    @Bean
    public BeanA getBeanA() {
        return beanA;
    }

    @Bean
    public BeanB getBeanB() {
        return beanB;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Piotr! This works beautifully - you deserve 10,000 upvotes for this, and I am sure they will sing songs about you in heaven.

Comment: For some reason with this approach, spring tries to create the actual bean anyway (instead of mock) and chokes on that... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have the same issue

Comment: Not spring but rather mockito tries to instantiate an actual bean if you are mocking a class. If you have any beans that have to be mocked in tests, they should be implementations of an interface, and injected via that interface. If you then mock the interface (rather than class), mockito won't attempt to instantiate that class.

Comment: I get No qualifying bean of type [class name] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2:

Comment: Try `@Primary` when declaring mock bean

Comment: What is the point? Why add the annotated fields and constructor with `initMocks`? Why not just `return Mockito.mock(BeanA.class)` in `getBeanA` ? This way it's simpler and there is less code. What am I missing?

Comment: @Oleg it sounds like you have your own solution, which you should probably post as an answer, so that the community can vote on it.

Answer (score 56):

Given:

```
@Service
public class MyService {
    @Autowired
    private MyDAO myDAO;

    // etc
}
```

You can have the class that is being tested loaded via autowiring, mock the dependency with Mockito, and then use Spring's ReflectionTestUtils to inject the mock into the class being tested.

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { MvcConfiguration.class })
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class MyServiceTest {
    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;

    private MyDAO myDAOMock;

    @Before
    public void before() {
        myDAOMock = Mockito.mock(MyDAO.class);
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(myService, "myDAO", myDAOMock);
    }

    // etc
}
```

Please note that before Spring 4.3.1, this method won't work with services behind a proxy (annotated with `@Transactional`, or `Cacheable`, for example). This has been fixed by [SPR-14050](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-14050).

For earlier versions, a solution is to unwrap the proxy, as described there: [Transactional annotation avoids services being mocked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12857981/transactional-annotation-avoids-services-being-mocked/17548683#17548683) (which is what `ReflectionTestUtils.setField` does by default now)

Comment: Double 
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
and I use different annotations for test class (same runner) but this approach works for me, thanks.

Comment: I was inspired a lot by "Please note that before Spring 4.3.1, this method won't work with services behind a proxy (annotated with @Transactional, or Cacheable, for example). This has been fixed by SPR-14050" . I just ran into this issue exactly and didn't get any clue until spotting this words.  THANKS A LOT!

Comment: This solution handles when you have wired up an entire application context and, for test purpose, wants to inject a mock in a random bean in your context. I used this answer to mock a feign client bean in order to avoid REST calls to other modules in a Module test.
I only got the InjectMock annotation to work when you are injecting mocks in a bean that you are about to test, not in a bean created by the Spring Application Configuration.

Comment: Nearly a whole day fluffing around trying to get @MockBean working without resetting the context and then I come across this gem. Exactly what I needed, cheers.

Comment: Works, although beware that the replaced field might not reset due to caching and some unrelated tests could break. E.g. in my test i replaced the password encoder with a mock one and a few other tests broke due to authorization failures.

Comment: @MattR: you can use [@MockInBean](https://github.com/antoinemeyer/mock-in-bean) as an alternative to `@MockBean` that does not reset the context and keep it clean. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66682864/1069426).

Answer (score 55):

If you're using Spring Boot 1.4, it has an awesome way of doing this. Just use new brand `@SpringBootTest` on your class and `@MockBean` on the field  and Spring Boot will create a mock of this type and it will inject it into the context (instead of injecting the original one):

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class MyTests {

    @MockBean
    private RemoteService remoteService;

    @Autowired
    private Reverser reverser;

    @Test
    public void exampleTest() {
        // RemoteService has been injected into the reverser bean
        given(this.remoteService.someCall()).willReturn("mock");
        String reverse = reverser.reverseSomeCall();
        assertThat(reverse).isEqualTo("kcom");
    }

}
```

On the other hand, if you're not using Spring Boot or are you using a previous version, you'll have to do a bit more work:

Create a `@Configuration` bean that injects your mocks into Spring context:

```
@Configuration
@Profile("useMocks")
public class MockConfigurer {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public MyBean myBeanSpy() {
        return mock(MyBean.class);
    }
}
```

Using `@Primary` annotation you're telling spring that this bean has priority if no qualifier are specified.

Make sure you annotate the class with `@Profile("useMocks")` in order to control which classes will use the mock and which ones will use the real bean.

Finally, in your test, activate `userMocks` profile:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = {Application.class})
@WebIntegrationTest
@ActiveProfiles(profiles={"useMocks"})
public class YourIntegrationTestIT {

    @Inject
    private MyBean myBean; //It will be the mock!


    @Test
    public void test() {
        ....
    }
}
```

If you don't want to use the mock but the real bean, just don't activate `useMocks` profile:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = {Application.class})
@WebIntegrationTest
public class AnotherIntegrationTestIT {

    @Inject
    private MyBean myBean; //It will be the real implementation!


    @Test
    public void test() {
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer should go to the top - @MockBean support in spring boot also can be used without spring-boot. You can use it in unit tests only so it works for all spring applications!

Comment: @Profile annotation you can set also on the bean definition method, to avoid creating separate configuration class

Comment: Great answer! I made a few changes to make it work with my old-school `web.xml` and  AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext setup. Had to use `@WebAppConfiguration` instead of `@WebIntegrationTest` and `@ContextHierarchy` with `@ContextConfiguration` instead of `@SpringApplicationConfiguration`.

Comment: I had to add the `@Primary` annotation for my case, since there was a failing call inside a `@PostConstruct` that I wanted to mock, but the `@PostConstruct`'s bean was created before my mock so it didn't use the mock (until I added `@Primary`).

Comment: `@MockBean` has a significant drawback: it may lead to the re-creation of your Spring context in your build test phase. (See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45587213/using-mockbean-in-tests-forces-reloading-of-application-context or [the problem with @MockBean](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-tests#2-the-problems-withmockbean)).

You can use [@MockInBean](https://github.com/antoinemeyer/mock-in-bean) as an alternative to @MockBean that does not reset the context. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66682864/1069426)

Comment: Great solution, also works with partial mocks (i.e. when you want to mock one bean, but leave the rest of the dependencies as-is).

Answer (score 20):

Since [1.8.3](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html#21) Mockito has `@InjectMocks` - this is incredibly useful. My JUnit tests are `@RunWith` the `MockitoJUnitRunner` and I build `@Mock` objects that satisfy all the dependencies for the class being tested, which are all injected when the private member is annotated with `@InjectMocks`.

I `@RunWith` the `SpringJUnit4Runner` for integration tests only now.

I will note that it does not seem to be able to inject `List<T>` in the same manner as Spring. It looks only for a Mock object that satisfies the `List`, and will not inject a list of Mock objects. The workaround for me was to use a `@Spy` against a manually instantiated list, and manually .add the mock object(s) to that list for unit testing. Maybe that was intentional, because it certainly forced me to pay close attention to what was being mocked together.

Comment: Yeah this is the best way. Springockito doesn't actually inject the mocks for whatever reason in my case.

Answer (score 14):

**Update:** There are now better, cleaner solutions to this problem. Please consider the other answers first.

I eventually found an answer to this by ronen on his blog. The problem I was having is due to the method `Mockito.mock(Class c)` declaring a return type of `Object`. Consequently Spring is unable to infer the bean type from the factory method return type.

[Ronen's solution](http://javadevelopmentforthemasses.blogspot.com/2008/07/mocking-spring-tests.html) is to create a `FactoryBean` implementation that returns mocks. The `FactoryBean` interface allows Spring to query the type of objects created by the factory bean.

My mocked bean definition now looks like:

```
<bean id="mockDaoFactory" name="dao" class="com.package.test.MocksFactory">
    <property name="type" value="com.package.Dao" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Updated link to Ronen's Solution: http://narkisr.com/blog/2008/2647754885089732945

Comment: I don't understand that, the factory method has return type Object ...  But the amra's solution has a generic return type so that Spring should recognize it... But the amra's solution doesn't work for me

Comment: Neither this solution,  spring doesn't infer the type of bean that is returned from the factoryBean hence No matching bean of type [ com.package.Dao ] ...

Comment: Way back machine: http://web.archive.org/web/20120806223839/http://javadevelopmentforthemasses.blogspot.com/2008/07/mocking-spring-tests.html

Comment: This link actually still works: http://javadevelopmentforthemasses.blogspot.com/2008/07/mocking-spring-tests.html Just disable link redirection in your browser and you'll see it, instead of being force to look at the 404 on his new blog.

Comment: Or do what I did.   Visit the original link - then you've got about 0.2 seconds before the content disappears and is replaced with the 404 message from the new blog.  That's just long enough to press Ctrl-A Ctrl-C to copy the content.  Then paste it into a text editor to read.

Answer (score 12):

As of Spring 3.2, this is no longer an issue.  Spring now supports Autowiring of the results of generic factory methods.  See the section entitled "Generic Factory Methods" in this blog post: http://spring.io/blog/2012/11/07/spring-framework-3-2-rc1-new-testing-features/.

The key point is:

> In Spring 3.2, generic return types for factory methods are now
>   properly inferred, and autowiring by type for mocks should work as
>   expected. As a result, custom work-arounds such as a
>   MockitoFactoryBean, EasyMockFactoryBean, or Springockito are likely no
>   longer necessary.

Which means this should work out of the box:

```
<bean id="dao" class="org.mockito.Mockito" factory-method="mock">
    <constructor-arg value="com.package.Dao" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 10):

If you're using **spring >= 3.0**, try using Springs `@Configuration` annotation to define part of the application context

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource("com/blah/blurk/rest-of-config.xml")
public class DaoTestConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ApplicationService applicationService() {
        return mock(ApplicationService.class);
    }

}
```

If you don't want to use the @ImportResource, it can be done the other way around too:

```
<beans>
    <!-- rest of your config -->

    <!-- the container recognize this as a Configuration and adds it's beans 
         to the container -->
    <bean class="com.package.DaoTestConfiguration"/>
</beans>
```

For more information, have a look at spring-framework-reference : [Java-based container configuration](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java)

Comment: Nice one.  I used this when the test I am testing is @Autowired in the actual test case.

Answer (score 9):

Below code works with autowiring - it is not the shortest version but useful when it should work only with standard spring/mockito jars.

```
<bean id="dao" class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean">
   <property name="target"> <bean class="org.mockito.Mockito" factory-method="mock"> <constructor-arg value="com.package.Dao" /> </bean> </property>
   <property name="proxyInterfaces"> <value>com.package.Dao</value> </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Worked for me. I had to unwrap the proxy in my test in order to verify it as described here: http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/aop/52011-need-to-unwrap-a-proxy-to-get-the-object-being-proxied

Answer (score 8):

Perhaps not the perfect solution, but I tend not to use spring to do DI for unit tests. the dependencies for a single bean (the class under test) usually aren't overly complex so I just do the injection directly in the test code.

Comment: I understand your approach. However, I find myself in this situation on a large legacy code base that doesn't easily allow for this - yet.

Comment: I have found the Mockito/Spring combo to be very useful when I need to test code that depends heavily on Spring aspects/AOP (for instance, when testing spring security rules). Although one is perfectly justified in claiming that such tests should be a integration test.

Comment: @Lars - agreed - the same could be said of the tests I am dealing with.

Answer (score 7):

I can do the following using Mockito:

```
<bean id="stateMachine" class="org.mockito.Mockito" factory-method="mock">
    <constructor-arg value="com.abcd.StateMachine"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Alexander. May I ask: does it wire-up correctly? If so which versions of Spring/Mockito are you using?

Comment: I want a spy not a mock. How to do that ?

Answer (score 6):

Posting a few examples based on the above approaches

With Spring:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:context.xml" })
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class TestServiceTest {
    @InjectMocks
    private TestService testService;
    @Mock
    private TestService2 testService2;
}
```

Without Spring:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class TestServiceTest {
    @InjectMocks
    private TestService testService = new TestServiceImpl();
    @Mock
    private TestService2 testService2;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Update** - new answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19454282/411229.  This answer only applies to those on Spring versions before 3.2.

I've looked for a while for a more definitive solution to this.  This blog post seems to cover all my needs and doesn't rely on ordering of bean declarations.  All credit to Mattias Severson.  http://www.jayway.com/2011/11/30/spring-integration-tests-part-i-creating-mock-objects/

Basically, implement a FactoryBean

```
package com.jayway.springmock;

import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.FactoryBean;

/**
 * A {@link FactoryBean} for creating mocked beans based on Mockito so that they 
 * can be {@link @Autowired} into Spring test configurations.
 *
 * @author Mattias Severson, Jayway
 *
 * @see FactoryBean
 * @see org.mockito.Mockito
 */
public class MockitoFactoryBean<T> implements FactoryBean<T> {

    private Class<T> classToBeMocked;

    /**
     * Creates a Mockito mock instance of the provided class.
     * @param classToBeMocked The class to be mocked.
     */
    public MockitoFactoryBean(Class<T> classToBeMocked) {
        this.classToBeMocked = classToBeMocked;
    }

    @Override
    public T getObject() throws Exception {
        return Mockito.mock(classToBeMocked);
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getObjectType() {
        return classToBeMocked;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSingleton() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Next update your spring config with the following:

```
<beans...>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.jayway.example"/>

    <bean id="someDependencyMock" class="com.jayway.springmock.MockitoFactoryBean">
        <constructor-arg name="classToBeMocked" value="com.jayway.example.SomeDependency" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking at [Springockito pace of development](https://bitbucket.org/kubek2k/springockito/commits/all) and [number of open issues](https://bitbucket.org/kubek2k/springockito/issues?status=new&status=open), I would be little bit worried to introduce it into my test suite stack nowadays. Fact that last release was done before Spring 4 release brings up questions like "Is it possible to easily integrate it with Spring 4?". I don't know, because I didn't try it. I prefer pure Spring approach if I need to mock Spring bean in integration test.

There is an option to fake Spring bean with just plain Spring features. You need to use `@Primary`, `@Profile` and `@ActiveProfiles` annotations for it. [I wrote a blog post on the topic.](https://lkrnac.net/blog/2015/12/mock-spring-bean-v2/)

Comment: Blog post link 404s

Comment: Sorry there was mistake in links numbering, fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

I use a combination of the approach used in answer by Markus T and a simple helper implementation of `ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar` that looks for a custom annotation (`@MockedBeans`) in which one can specify which classes are to be mocked. I believe that this approach results in a concise unit test with some of the boilerplate code related to mocking removed.

Here's how a sample unit test looks with that approach:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(loader=AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
public class ExampleServiceIntegrationTest {

    //our service under test, with mocked dependencies injected
    @Autowired
    ExampleService exampleService;

    //we can autowire mocked beans if we need to used them in tests
    @Autowired
    DependencyBeanA dependencyBeanA;

    @Test
    public void testSomeMethod() {
        ...
        exampleService.someMethod();
        ...
        verify(dependencyBeanA, times(1)).someDependencyMethod();
    }

    /**
     * Inner class configuration object for this test. Spring will read it thanks to
     * @ContextConfiguration(loader=AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class) annotation on the test class.
     */
    @Configuration
    @Import(TestAppConfig.class) //TestAppConfig may contain some common integration testing configuration
    @MockedBeans({DependencyBeanA.class, DependencyBeanB.class, AnotherDependency.class}) //Beans to be mocked
    static class ContextConfiguration {

        @Bean
        public ExampleService exampleService() {
            return new ExampleService(); //our service under test
        }
    }
}
```

To make this happen you need to define two simple helper classes - custom annotation (`@MockedBeans`) and a custom 
`ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar` implementation. `@MockedBeans` annotation definition needs to be annotated with `@Import(CustomImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar.class)` and the `ImportBeanDefinitionRgistrar` needs to add mocked beans definitions to the configuration in it's `registerBeanDefinitions` method.

If you like the approach you can find sample [implementations](https://github.com/knes1/springmockedtests/tree/master/src/test/java/com/knesek/springmockedtests/com/knesek/springmockedtests/util) on my [blogpost](http://knes1.github.io/blog/2014/2014-08-18-concise-integration-tests-that-contain-mocks-in-spring-framework.html).

Comment: you made my day. neat.

Answer (score 1):

I found a similar answer as teabot to create a MockFactory that provides the mocks. I used the following example to create the mock factory (since the link to narkisr are dead):
http://hg.randompage.org/java/src/407e78aa08a0/projects/bookmarking/backend/spring/src/test/java/org/randompage/bookmarking/backend/testUtils/MocksFactory.java

```
<bean id="someFacade" class="nl.package.test.MockFactory">
    <property name="type" value="nl.package.someFacade"/>
</bean>
```

This also helps to prevent that Spring wants to resolve the injections from the mocked bean.

Answer (score 1):

```
<bean id="mockDaoFactory" name="dao" class="com.package.test.MocksFactory">
    <property name="type" value="com.package.Dao" />
</bean>
```

this ^ works perfectly well if declared first/early in the XML file. Mockito 1.9.0/Spring 3.0.5

Answer (score 1):

I developed a solution based on the proposal of Kresimir Nesek. I added a new annotation *@EnableMockedBean* in order to make the code a bit cleaner and modular.

```
@EnableMockedBean
@SpringBootApplication
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes=MockedBeanTest.class)
public class MockedBeanTest {

    @MockedBean
    private HelloWorldService helloWorldService;

    @Autowired
    private MiddleComponent middleComponent;

    @Test
    public void helloWorldIsCalledOnlyOnce() {

        middleComponent.getHelloMessage();

        // THEN HelloWorldService is called only once
        verify(helloWorldService, times(1)).getHelloMessage();
    }

}
```

I have written a [post](http://therore.net/injecting-mockito-mocks-into-the-spring-context/) explaining it.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to migrate your project to Spring Boot 1.4. After that you can use new annotation [`@MockBean`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-mocking-beans) to fake your `com.package.Dao`

Answer (score 0):

Today I found out that a spring context where I declared a  before the Mockito  beans, was failing to load. 
After moving the  AFTER the mocks, the app context was loaded successfully. 
Take care :)

Comment: There is something missing. 8-) You moved what after the mocks?

Answer (score 0):

For the record, all my tests correctly work by just making the fixture lazy-initialized, e.g.:

```
<bean id="fixture"
      class="it.tidalwave.northernwind.rca.embeddedserver.impl.DefaultEmbeddedServer"
      lazy-init="true" /> <!-- To solve Mockito + Spring problems -->

<bean class="it.tidalwave.messagebus.aspect.spring.MessageBusAdapterFactory" />

<bean id="applicationMessageBus"
      class="org.mockito.Mockito" factory-method="mock">
    <constructor-arg value="it.tidalwave.messagebus.MessageBus" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.mockito.Mockito" factory-method="mock">
    <constructor-arg value="javax.servlet.ServletContext" />
</bean>
```

I suppose the rationale is the one Mattias explains [here](http://www.jayway.com/2011/11/30/spring-integration-tests-part-i-creating-mock-objects/) (at the bottom of the post), that a workaround is changing the order the beans are declared - lazy initialization is "sort of" having the fixture declared at the end.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using spring boot 2.2+, you can use [@MockInBean](https://github.com/antoinemeyer/mock-in-bean) as an alternative to `@MockBean` and keep your Spring context clean:

```
@SpringBootTest
public class MyServiceTest {

    @MockInBean(MyService.class)
    private ServiceToMock serviceToMock;

    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        Mockito.when(serviceToMock.returnSomething()).thenReturn(new Object());
        myService.doSomething();
    }
}
```

*disclaimer: I created this library to avoid Spring Context re-creation caused by @MockBean/@SpringBean that leads to slow build test phases (see [Using @MockBean in tests forces reloading of Application Context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45587213/using-mockbean-in-tests-forces-reloading-of-application-context) or [the problem with @MockBean](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-tests#2-the-problems-withmockbean))*

Answer (score 0):

JUnit5 example.

First you have some service that wires in some dependent object.

```java
@Component
public class MyService {
   private final MyRepository repository;

   public MyService(MyRepository repository) {
      this.repository = repository;
   }

   public MyData serviceFindBy(String id) {
      return repository.findById(id).get();
   }
}
```

Then you have some dependent object, here a Repository:

```java
@Repository
public interface MyRepository extends MongoRepository<MyData, String> {
   Optional<MyData> findById(String id);
}
```

This is how the JUnit test would look:

```java
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

@SpringBootTest(classes = {MyService.class})
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class MyServiceTest {

    @InjectMocks
    MyService myService;

    @MockBean
    MyRepository myRepository;

    @Test
    public void testFindById() {
        when(myRepository.findById(any())).thenReturn(new MyData("123"));
        MyData myData = myService.serviceFindBy("123");
        assertEquals("123", myData.getId());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a complex EventListeners integration testing scenario, the simplest and fastest approach in my case was to provide a mocked bean or discard it from the context.

I ended up choosing to discard it with the following approach.

I create a jUnit extension class:

```java
public class DisableBeanExtension implements BeforeAllCallback {

    @Override
    public void beforeAll(final ExtensionContext extensionContext) {
        final Class<?> testClass = extensionContext.getRequiredTestClass();
        final DisableBean disableBeanAnnotation = testClass.getAnnotation(DisableBean.class);

        if (disableBeanAnnotation != null) {
            final var applicationContext = (ConfigurableApplicationContext) SpringExtension.getApplicationContext(extensionContext);
            final var registry = (BeanDefinitionRegistry) applicationContext.getBeanFactory();
            for (Class<?> classType : disableBeanAnnotation.classes()) {
                registry.removeBeanDefinition(StringUtils.uncapitalize(classType.getSimpleName()));
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I created a custom annotation:

```java
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Inherited
@ExtendWith(DisableBeanExtension.class)
public @interface DisableBean {

    Class<?>[] classes() default {};

}
```

And finally, I used the custom annotation on my integration test class:

```java
// Other annotations to set up the test class have been omitted
@DisableBean(classes = {BeanToRemoveOne.class, BeanToRemoveTwo.class})
class MyIntegrationTest {

    // Other dependencies and scenarios to set up the test cases have been omitted

}
```

It's worked fine to me!