# Spring mvc junit test serrice

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, testing, junit

I'm using spring mvc.
I want to test my service with Junit.
I want to test the inclusion of a new user
I write the class test:

```
@ContextConfiguration("/dispatcher-servlet.xml")
public class ServizioUtenteTest {

    @Autowired
    private ServizioUtente servizioutente;

    @Test
    public void testAggiungiUtente() {
        //fail("Not yet implemented");
        Utente utente=new Docente();

        utente.setCognome("Professore");
        utente.setPassword("tetxts");
        utente.setUsername("xxxx");

        servizioutente.aggiungiUtente(utente);


    }

    @Test

}
```

When I run the test I get:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.rol.test.ServizioUtenteTest.testAggiungiUtente(ServizioUtenteTest.java:61)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
....)
```

The error is thrown on the line, why?
help me!?

Comment: On *what* line? And what's that spurious `@Test` annotation doing?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner`:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("/dispatcher-servlet.xml")
public class ServizioUtenteTest {
  //...
```

## See also

- [Creating unitary tests in Spring 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5583962)
- [*11. Testing*](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html)