# Mocking Spring beans

Tags: spring, mocking, autowired

I'd like to continue [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2457239/306488) question.

These answers [foo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457239/injecting-mockito-mocks-into-a-spring-bean/2461385#2461385) and [bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457239/injecting-mockito-mocks-into-a-spring-bean/3512926#3512926) are exactly what I would need.

But for the [bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457239/injecting-mockito-mocks-into-a-spring-bean/3512926#3512926) example spring doesn't infer the type of bean that is returned from generic mock() method. But actually it's exactly the same as in the MockFactoryBean case, that is working.

```
class MockFactoryBean<T> implements FactoryBean<T> {

    private Class<T> type;

    public void setType(final Class<T> type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    @Override
    public T getObject() throws Exception {
        return (T) Mockito.mock(type);
    }

    @Override
    public Class<T> getObjectType() {
        return type;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSingleton() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

plus

```
<bean id="mockFactory" name="someType" class="com.example.MocksFactory" >
    <property name="type" value="com.example.SomeType" />
</bean>
```

BUT using `org.mockito.Mockito` and `mock()` factory method doesn't work

```
<bean id="dao" class="org.mockito.Mockito" factory-method="mock"> 
    <constructor-arg value="com.example.SomeType" /> 
</bean>
```

and one gets No matching bean of type [ com.example.SomeType ] ... when Autowiring.

@Autowired
public SomeType someType;

Why is that ?

the way with MockFactoryBean is quite inconvenient because if you have to mock many beans, you end up like this :

```
<bean id="mockFactory1" name="metadataExtractor" class="tests.base.MocksFactory" >
    <property name="type" value="processing.MetadataExtractor" />
</bean>
<bean id="mockFactory2" name="fileValidator" class="tests.base.MocksFactory" >
    <property name="type" value="validation.file.FileValidator" />
</bean>
<bean id="mockFactory3" name="documentMatcher" class="tests.base.MocksFactory" >
    <property name="type" value="validation.matching.DocumentMatcher" />
</bean>
<bean id="mockFactory4" name="uploadMatcher" class="tests.base.MocksFactory">
    <property name="type" value="validation.matching.UploadMatcher" />
</bean>
<bean id="mockFactory5" name="tempFileLocalService" class="tests.base.MocksFactory">
    <property name="type" value="service.TempFileLocalService" />
</bean>
<bean id="mockFactory6" name="orderLocalService" class="tests.base.MocksFactory">
    <property name="type" value="service.OrderLocalService" />
</bean>
<bean id="mockFactory7" name="counterLocalService" class="tests.base.MocksFactory">
    <property name="type" value="service.CounterLocalService" />
</bean>
```

Because without id & name it doesn't infer the type.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12352317/448078) example works for me pretty cool.

Answer (score 7):

When XML file should work with standard spring/mockito jars you can use ProxyFactoryBean and it works with autowiring (tested on Spring 2.5).

```
<bean id="dao" class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean">
   <property name="target"> <bean class="org.mockito.Mockito" factory-method="mock"> <constructor-arg value="com.package.Dao" /> </bean> </property>
   <property name="proxyInterfaces"> <value>com.package.Dao</value> </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

I take that a step further with a bit more code in the FactoryBean and keep the real mock creation in my test class. Instead, my FactoryBean generates dynamic proxies as needed on Spring startup--which don't suffer the typing problem you're seeing--and the tests can wire in mocks as desired. I wrote a [blog post](http://shotgunsandpenguins.blogspot.com/2011/04/effective-testing-of-jersey-resource.html) that describes how to do it. The post specifically deals with testing a JAX-RS resource class, but the [last section](http://shotgunsandpenguins.blogspot.com/2011/04/effective-testing-of-jersey-resource.html#d0e53) can pretty much stand on its own as an alternate way of doing what you're attempting if you blur out the JAX-RS stuff.

Comment: it's nicely done but I got used to leave behind only solutions that are obvious on the first sight. This demands a lot of concentration to even get it and it will so repeatedly for other programmers and me myself after some time :-)

Comment: @lisak: I enjoy using it for exactly the opposite reason: it lets you keep writing tests the same way as usual, so there's nothing new to get used to.

Answer (score 0):

What I came up with:

```
public class SpringMocks implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SpringMocks.class);
    private final List<Class<?>> classes;

    public SpringMocks(List<Class<?>> classes) {
        this.classes = classes;
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        if (applicationContext instanceof GenericApplicationContext) {
            GenericApplicationContext context = (GenericApplicationContext) applicationContext;
            DefaultListableBeanFactory beanFactory = context.getDefaultListableBeanFactory();

            for (Class<?> className : classes) {
                String beanName = RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(10);
                Object singletonObject = Mockito.mock(className);
                beanFactory.registerSingleton(beanName, singletonObject);
            }
        } else {
            logger.warn("unable to add beans to the context!");
        }
    }
}
```

And the definition:

```
<bean class="com.whatever.SpringMocks">
    <constructor-arg index="0">
        <list>
            <value>com.whatever.enricher.Enricher</value>
            <value>com.whatever.nimbus.NimbusOrderDao</value>
            <value>com.whatever.nimbus.NimbusAllocationDao</value>
            <value>com.whatever.nimbus.NimbusExecutionDao</value>
            <value>com.whatever.nimbus.NimbusBookingInstructionDao</value>
            <value>com.whatever.services.SettingsService</value>
            <value>com.whatever.matchers.utils.CVDataRetriever</value>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Hope it will help those who are looking for the solution