# How to mock DefaultMessageListenerContainer

Tags: java, spring, mocking, mockito

I'm struggling with mocking (using Mockito) the `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` (`org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer`). Here is my code:

```
@Mock
private DefaultMessageListenerContainer defaultMessageListenerContainer;

@Before
public void init() {

    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks( this );
    incomingFeedController = new IncomingFeedControllerImpl();

}

@Test 
public void testHandleConnectionState() { 
    List< DefaultMessageListenerContainer > listeners = 
        new ArrayList< DefaultMessageListenerContainer >(); 
    listeners.add( defaultMessageListenerContainer ); 
    incomingFeedController.setContainers( listeners ); 
    when( defaultMessageListenerContainer.isRunning() ).thenReturn( false );
}
```

Then I would like to do some proper tests like:

```
when( defaultMessageListenerContainer.isRunning() ).thenReturn( false );
```

But after junit run this line end up with:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractJmsListeningContainer.isRunning(AbstractJmsListeningContainer.java:312)
    at com.source.etf.manager.integrationgateway.feedcontroller.IncomingFeedControllerTest.testHandleConnectionState(IncomingFeedControllerTest.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTestMethod(MethodRoadie.java:98)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:79)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:87)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:77)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.invokeTestMethod(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.runMethods(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:51)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner$1.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:27)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:37)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

I also checked the `AbstractJmsListeningContainer` and here is the code where NPE occures:

```
public final boolean isRunning() {
    synchronized (this.lifecycleMonitor) {
        return (this.running && runningAllowed());
    }
}
```

What I found is that the `lifecycleMonitor` object is not being instantiated. This object is declared in `AbstractJmsListeningContainer` just at the top:

```
protected final Object lifecycleMonitor = new Object();
```

Any idea how to properly mock `DefaultMessageListenerContainer`?

Comment: Similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457239/injecting-mockito-mocks-into-a-spring-bean

Comment: Why do you *want* to mock it?  Your code should have no dependency on `DefaultMessageListenerContainer`, it's a Spring infrastructure component.

Answer (score 1):

You still need to set the mock on the object you are initializing.

I see that you are testing `IncomingFeedControllerImpl`, and it is likely that your mocked object is a member of an instance of this class.  Because you are not setting your mocked `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` on your `IncomingFeedControllerImpl` explicitly the `AbstractJmsListeningContainer` (which is probably `@Autowired`) is still hanging around and not being mocked.

You will need to either inject it by using a setter method or a constructor. (you can also `@Autowired` it)

Comment: Nope. This is not the case. Tried it already. This has definitely something to do with this lifecycleMonitor not being instantiated.

Comment: Well, according to your code, you are trying to Mock your `DefaultMessageListenerContainer`, and by receiving an `AbstractJmsListeningContainer`, means that the mocked object was never set on your `IncomingFeedController`.

Comment: I just ommited this part but here is my test code:
     
    `@Test
    public void testHandleConnectionState() {

        List< DefaultMessageListenerContainer > listeners = new ArrayList< DefaultMessageListenerContainer >();
        listeners.add( defaultMessageListenerContainer );

        incomingFeedController.setContainers( listeners );

        when( defaultMessageListenerContainer.isRunning() ).thenReturn( false );`

Comment: Edit your question and add the test.

Answer (score 1):

Mockito can't mock final classes or final methods. These constraints are enforced by the JVM itself. Mocking such code would requite to actually rewrite the class bytecode and load it in another classloader. This lead to very complex code; PowerMock went into that direction, and the code is difficult to maintain.

Also don't mock types you don't own, see the 4-5 first results on [google](http://www.google.fr/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=don%27t%20mock%20type%20you%20don%27t%20own). Why would you need to mock Spring types in a unit test. You should either create some indirection to avoid Spring adherence or write integration tests; the latter seems more appropriate as it is related to JMS.

Answer (score 0):

You will either need to use PowerMock, or to do an integration test as @Brice suggests.  Here's how to do it in PowerMock:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.class)
public class MyTestClass {

    // cannot use the @Mock annotation
    private DefaultMessageListenerContainer defaultMessageListenerContainer;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        // This should allow the mocking of final methods as well.
        defaultMessageListenerContainer = 
            PowerMockito.mock(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.class);
        incomingFeedController = new IncomingFeedControllerImpl();

    }

    @Test 
    public void testHandleConnectionState() { 
        List< DefaultMessageListenerContainer > listeners = 
            new ArrayList< DefaultMessageListenerContainer >(); 
        listeners.add( defaultMessageListenerContainer ); 
        incomingFeedController.setContainers( listeners ); 
        when( defaultMessageListenerContainer.isRunning() ).thenReturn( false );
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes `@PrepareForTest` instruction is mandatory, otherwise PowerMock won't _prepare_ this class in the temporary PowerMock classloader's realm

Answer (score 0):

```
private DefaultMessageListenerContainer createFailingContainer() {
    DefaultMessageListenerContainer container = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer() {
        @Override
        public void start() throws JmsException {
            throw new MyJmsException("TEST");
        }

        @Override
        public void stop() throws JmsException {
            throw new MyJmsException("TEST");
        }
    };
    return container;
}

class MyJmsException extends JmsException {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public MyJmsException(String msg) {
        super(msg);
    }
}
```