# How to mock a spring bean?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mockito, powermock

I'm trying to mock an class that uses JAXRS and this class are a spring component.

```
@Component
public class PostmanClient {

  private WebTarget target;

  public PostmanClient() {
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    target = client.target(...);
  }

  public String send(String xml) {
    Builder requestBuilder = target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_TYPE);
    Response response = requestBuilder.post(Entity.entity(xml, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_TYPE));
    return response.readEntity(String.class);
  }
}
```

This is my test method:

```
@Test
public void processPendingRegistersWithAutomaticSyncJob() throws Exception {
  PostmanClient postmanClient = mock(PostmanClient.class);
  String response = "OK";
  whenNew(PostmanClient.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(postmanClient);
  when(postmanClient.send("blablabla")).thenReturn(response);

  loadApplicationContext(); // applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/test-context.xml");
}
```

When i debug the postmanClient instance, its a instance created by Spring and not a mock.
How can i avoid this behavior and get a mock instance ?

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to mix mocking into an integration test. Either don't load beans via Spring with `loadApplicationContext`, or use a different profile to load a manually stubbed PostmanClient for your tests.

Comment: Yes, but i don't want create a restful server to respond the postmanClient. The other way is to use a framework that mock restful services like restito or mock-server.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10906945/mockito-junit-and-spring/10924843#10924843 This question should give you some idea on how to do it.  Though I am not recommend doing so, especially for unit testing

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PowerMock with Spring, you should consider following tips:
1. Use @RunWith(SpringJunit4Runner.class)
2. Use @ContextConfiguration("/test-context.xml") // load spring context before test
3. Use @PrepareForTest(....class) // to mock static method
4. Use [PowerMockRule](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/PowerMockRule)
5. The simplest way to mock a spring bean is to use [springockito](https://bitbucket.org/kubek2k/springockito/wiki/Home)

**Back To You Question**:
If I don't understand you wrong, you have `PostmanClient` defined in spring context, which means, you only need use `springockito` to achieve your goal, just follow the tutorial on springockito page.

Comment: I don't want to use SpringJunit4Runner because i need to load datasets on database with DBUnit before spring context load. I try to use spring-test-dbunit but the framework listener always execute after spring context listener. Because of this i choose to load dataset and create the application context programmatically. Doing this way i need to create the mocks before all mentioned above.

Comment: @SandroSimas, you may use jUnit Spring Rule. Like in my example. https://github.com/thekingnothing/mockito-junit-spring-rules But I doubt that you need mock object in integration tests.

Answer (score 0):

You can use BDD framework Spock to write UT for your Spring Framework. With Spock Spring extension (Maven: groupId:org.spockframework, artifactId:spock-spring), you can load Spring context in your unit test.

```
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
class MyServiceSpec extends Specification {
    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository
}
```

If you have some beans you want to mock them instead of loading from Spring context, you can add following annotation on the bean you want to mock.

```
@ReplaceWithMock
```

This [article](http://www.kubrynski.com/2014/01/spring-integration-testing-with-spock.html) has the detailed intro about how to write UT for your Spring app with Spock.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure what is wrong with your implementation. Maybe PostmanClient should be an interface instead of class?

However I've implemented a similar unit test in my practice/test project. Maybe it will help:

https://github.com/oipat/poht/blob/683b401145d4a4c2bace49f356a5aa401fe81eb1/backend/src/test/java/org/tapiok/blogi/service/impl/PostServiceImplTest.java

Comment: But you are not using Spring

Answer (score 0):

Register your mock with [Spring-ReInject](https://github.com/sgri/spring-reinject) before the application context starts in your test's constructor. The original bean will be replaced with a mock, and the mock will be used by Spring everywhere, including injected fields. The original bean will be never created.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option to fake Spring bean with just plain Spring features. You need to use `@Primary`, `@Profile` and `@ActiveProfiles` annotations for it.

[I wrote a blog post on the topic.](https://lkrnac.net/blog/2015/12/mock-spring-bean-v2/)

Answer (score 0):

I've created the [example](https://github.com/thekingnothing/mockito-junit-spring-rules) to answer another question, but also cover your case. Simple replace `MockitoJUnitRunner` via `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner`.

In nutshell, I create Java Spring Configuration which includes only classes which should be tested/mocked and returns mocked object instead really object, and then give Spring does it work. Very simple and flexible solution.

It also works fine with `MvcMock`

Answer (score 0):

As of Spring Boot 1.4.x you can use new annotation called [@MockBean](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-mocking-beans).