# How to Unit Test an interface that is always Autowired (Java)

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, autowired

So I have an interface, let's call it X

So in the regular code i have:

```
public class doStuff()
{
@Autowired
private X x;

public stuff()
{
x.doYourThing();
}
}
```

I have no idea how to test this though.

If i try:

```
public class XTest()
{
  @Autowired
  private X x;
  public void test(){
  string val = x.FillUpVal();
  assertTrue("It didn't work",val=="hi");
  }

}
```

I get x as null so it immediately throws a NullPointerException and fails the test.  I'm looking for some guidance as to the proper way to go about this.

Comment: Needs more clarification on what you want to test: 1) how `doStuff()` behaves when `X` behaves in certain ways (use a mock) or 2) how `doStuff()` behaves when wired up with the real X that would be used at runtime (use Spring's Test Context library)

Answer (score 2):

You can in fact @Autowire a mock object. I recommend Mockito framework. 
More info and examples: http://code.google.com/p/mockito/

[Injecting Mockito mocks into a Spring bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457239/injecting-mockito-mocks-into-a-spring-bean)

More on mocks:

> In object-oriented programming, mock objects are simulated objects
>   that mimic the behavior of real objects in controlled ways. A
>   programmer typically creates a mock object to test the behavior of
>   some other object, in much the same way that a car designer uses a
>   crash test dummy to simulate the dynamic behavior of a human in
>   vehicle impacts.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object