# ReflectionTestUtils not working with @Autowired in Spring Test

Tags: spring, service, mockito, autowired

I am trying to add mock object in CourseServiceImpl's courseDao field but it is not working.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(
    locations = {"file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/config/servlet-config.xml"}
)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public final class CourseServiceTest {
  @Mock
  private CourseDao courseDao;
  @Autowired
  private CourseService courseService;
  @Before
  public void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
  }

@Test
  public void testCourseServiceNotNull() {
    assertNotNull(courseService);
    assertNotNull(courseDao);
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(courseService, "courseDao", courseDao, CourseDao.class);
  }
```

The reflection statement throws an error that field "courseDao" didn't found. But, when I create an object using new operator then it works fine.

```
ReflectionTestUtils.setField(new CourseServiceImpl(), "courseDao", courseDao, CourseDao.class);
```

**servlet-config.xml**

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<mvc:resources location="pdfs" mapping="/pdfs/**" />

<security:global-method-security
    pre-post-annotations="enabled" />

<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
    p:prefix="/WEB-INF/view/" p:suffix=".jsp" p:order="2" />

<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver"
    p:contentNegotiationManager-ref="contentNegId" p:defaultViews-ref="defaultViewList"
    p:order="1" />

<bean id="contentNegId"
    class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.web.accept.PathExtensionContentNegotiationStrategy">
            <constructor-arg>
                <map>
                    <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
                    <entry key="xml" value="application/xml" />
                </map>
            </constructor-arg>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<util:list id="defaultViewList">
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJackson2JsonView" />
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xml.MarshallingView">
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller"
                p:autodetectAnnotations="true" />
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
</util:list>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver"
    p:order="0" />

<bean id="localeResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver"
    p:defaultLocale="en" />

<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource"
    p:basename="messages" />

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:messages.properties" />

<import resource="/hibernate-config.xml" />
<import resource="/hibernate-config-test.xml" />
```

**hibernate-config-test.xml**

```
<bean id="myDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close" p:driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        p:url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/school-repo-test" p:username="user"
        p:password="password" />


    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean"
        p:dataSource-ref="myDataSource" p:hibernateProperties-ref="hibernateProps"
        p:annotatedClasses-ref="mapClasses">
    </bean>

    <util:list id="mapClasses">
        <value>org.school.model.Course</value>
        <value>org.school.model.Role</value>
        <value>org.school.model.Staff</value>
        <value>org.school.model.Student</value>
        <value>org.school.model.Subject</value>
    </util:list>

    <util:properties id="hibernateProps">
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
    </util:properties>

    <bean id="txManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager"
        p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory" />
```

Apart from profile name, rest is same for hibernate-config file.

**CourseServiceImpl**

```
@Service(value = "courseService")
@Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public class CourseServiceImpl implements CourseService {
  @Autowired
  private MessageSource messageSource;
  @Autowired
  private CourseDao courseDao;
  @Autowired
  private ApplicationContext context;
```

Please advise.

Comment: Please provide `servlet-config.xml` contents.

Comment: @SergeyBespalov Updated it in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `CourseServiceImpl` class has `@Transactional` annotation which means that bean instance wrapped with `"Transactional"` proxy before it injected as dependency in `CourseServiceTest` and all other beans in Spring context. Such proxy instance hides all the `private` fields of original `CourseServiceImpl` instance.

So you cannot access fields you want because injected `courseService` instance is not the original `CourseServiceImpl` class any more, it is dynamic `cglib` or `JDK` proxy class.

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34477414/6825250)  solution can be used in your case.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So, when I create instance using new operator then it won't wrapped with `"Transactional"` proxy, is this correct? If yes, do we usually test the service layer by creating instance using new operator?

Comment: >>> "So, when I create instance using new operator then it won't wrapped with "Transactional" proxy, is this correct?"

Yes

>>>" If yes, do we usually test the service layer by creating instance using new operator?"
No. In case of Spring services must be injected, like it already done in your Test.

Comment: Thanks @Sergey for your reply.

Comment: @RaviNain you got the answer to your question?

Comment: Yes, got it. It works how I wanted it to. Thanks again!