# Mockito with transactional annotated method

Tags: annotations, mockito, transactional

We've got a class with a method with an transactional annotation

```
public class MyHandler extends BaseHandler {

    @Transactional
    public void annotatedMethod(String parameter) throws Exception {
    }
```

As soon as we try to make a test using mockito and its annotations

```
@InjectMocks
private Controller controller;

@Mock
private MyHandler myHandler;
```

we have a null pointer exception when executing the following line

```
Mockito.doCallRealMethod().when(myHandler).annotatedMethod(Matchers.any());
```

We have tried to use the same solution as in [Transactional annotation avoids services being mocked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12857981/transactional-annotation-avoids-services-being-mocked) with no luck.

We're new with mockito, we have no idea how to solve this.
Any clues?

Thank you very much,
Elena

Comment: Hi Elena, is `MyHandler` the class under test? If so, then mocking it might not work. The `@Transactional` annotation won't affect the behaviour of `Mockito` when used as described. It's hard to know exactly what the root cause of your problem is without some error output. My guess is that the _real method_ you're delegating to, relies on other methods within `MyHandler` and gets a null back from them when calling them on the mock.
When you don't set up alternatives, all functions on mockito objects return null, false, 0, etc.

Comment: Helllo Ashley, I've solved the issue, it was not related with the annotation.It was that Mockito was returning null. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

you can try this way to mock the data. I have the similar NullPointerException and this way helped me.

```
@InjectMocks
private Controller controller;

@Mock
private MyHandler myHandler;

@Test
void testingMethod() {
    when(myHandler.annotatedMethod(Mockito.any())).thenReturn("something");
}
```