# Mocking the find method of EntityManager using Mockito?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, mockito

I have a piece of code that reads something like this:

entityManager.find(SomeClass.class, Long id, OtherClass.class, Session session);

Can I use Mockito to mock it out and return a desired value?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Yes, something like this will do it:

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.Test;

....

   @Test
   public void yourMockTest(){

    // create your Mock
    EntityManager entityManager = mock(EntityManager.class);

    // instantiate your args
    Class clazz = SomeClass.class;
    Long id = 1000L;
    Class otherClazz = OtherClass.class
    Session session = new SessionImpl();

    // instantate return object
    SomeClass returnMe = new SomeClass();

    // mock
    when(entityManager.find(any(), any(), any(), any()).thenReturn(returnMe);

    // execute
    Object returned = entityManager.find(clazz, id, otherClazz, session);

    // assert
    assertEquals(returnMe, returned);
   }
```

**Edit:** `chill` makes the good point you'll likely be dealing with an `EntityManager` in some other class. [This old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15228777/how-does-mockito-injectmocks-work) demonstrates how to use Mockito to inject mocks into other objects.

Comment: In a real situation, OP would probably be calling a service method. `@Mock` would be used to annotate an `EntityManager` field in the test and `@InjectMocks` would be used to annotate a `ServiceClass` field in the test. That way, the test would call something like `myServiceClass.doServiceAction()`, which will call the mocked `EntityManager` as part of its code.

Comment: Agreed... This old question dives into that in more detail: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15228777/how-does-mockito-injectmocks-work

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is yes. EntityManager is an interface, perfectly "mock-able" with Mockito. It'd be something like this:

```
EntityManager mocked = mock(EntityManager.class);
when(mocked.find(any(), any(), any(), any()).thenReturn(yourMockedValue)
```