# Using Mockito annotations with spring

Tags: java, spring, mockito

I am using spring in my application and I want to write unit tests for all my classes. I call few external webservices from my application and i want to mock them using Mockito since I just want to test my functionality.

Lets say I have the following scenario

This is my webservice interface

```
public interface MyWebService {
    public String getSomeData(int id);
}
```

I use the above service this way

```
public interface MyService {
    int doSomethingElse(String str);
}

public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {

    private MyWebService myWebService;

    int doSomethingElse(String str) {
        .....
        myWebService.getSomeData(id);
        ...
    }
}

public interface MyService1 {
    Stirng methodToBeTested();
}


public class Class1 implements MyService1{
    @Resource
    private MyService myService;

    public Stirng methodToBeTested() {
        myService.doSomethingElse("..");
    }
}
```

I wrote the uint test case as below. I am spying MyService here so as to run the unit test.

```
public class class1Test {

    @Spy
    MyService myService;

    @Resource
    @InjectMocks
    Class1 class1;

    public void setUPTest() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    Mockito.doReturn(123).when(myService).doSomethingElse("someString");
    }

    @Test
    public void methodToBeTestedTest() {
        this.setUPTest();
            ...
            class1.methodToBeTested();
    }

}
```

When I run the test, what I see is that, I get the value from the webservice insted of what i mention while stubbing.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457239/injecting-mockito-mocks-into-a-spring-bean

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved this by using spring java config. I extended my default config file in my test config file.

```
    @Configuration
    public class TestConfig extends DefaultConfig {

      @Bean
      public MyService myService() {
        return Mockito.spy(new MyServiceImpl());
      }
    }
```

Now my test class goes like this

```
public class class1Test {

    @Resource
    MyService myService;

    @Resource
    Class1 class1;

    public void setUPTest() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    Mockito.doReturn(123).when(myService).doSomethingElse("someString");
    }

    @Test
    public void methodToBeTestedTest() {
        this.setUPTest();
            ...
            class1.methodToBeTested();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

A `@Spy` is used to spy on what happens when calling services (and useful to eg. assert the presence or absence of transitive method invocations), what you want is the `@Mock` annotation:

```
public class class1Test {
    @Mock MyService myService;
    ...
```

This will result in all `myService` methods returning null, bar those you override with `doReturn`/`when`.

Incidentally, rather than calling `setUpTest()` from your test methods, you should annotate it with `@Before`.

Cheers,

Comment: I have used spy here because, there are other methods in MyService which dosent need to be stubbed.(This is just a sample code which resembles mine)

Answer (score 3):

To replace your Bean with mock in some test use [Springockito](https://bitbucket.org/kubek2k/springockito/wiki/Home) or better [Springockito-annotations](https://bitbucket.org/kubek2k/springockito/wiki/springockito-annotations).

Something like this should work:

```
@ContextConfiguration(loader = SpringockitoContextLoader.class,
    locations = "classpath:/context.xml")
public class SpringockitoAnnotationsMocksIntegrationTest extends AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests {

    @WrapWithSpy
    private MyService innerBean;

    @Resource  
    Class1 class1;

    public void setUPTest() {        
        Mockito.doReturn(123).when(myService).doSomethingElse("someString");
    }

    @Test
    public void methodToBeTestedTest() {
    this.setUPTest();
        ...
        class1.methodToBeTested();
    }
```

}

Comment: I have seen the above link. How do I inject "myService" spy into "class1" using springockito. In Class1, "MyService" is private and has no setter.

Comment: @coder, updated. If in your real context myService is injected to Class1 - it will be injected with WrapWithSpy too.

Comment: I am using spring java config for initialisation of beans, springockito dosent support it.

Comment: @coder : seems to work with SpringockitoAnnotatedContextLoader.class

Comment: Thanks! That solved my issue. But I used
"ReplaceWithMock" with "Autowired" annotations combination to spy on a real spring bean.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean *anyString()* rather than "someString" in your `setUp` method? This can also be `eq("someString")` if you are calling your method with a specific string.

From my understanding of Mockito I don't use spys since they probably indicate a class design issue. Why don't you `@Mock` the whole of `MyService`, so;

```
@Mock MyService myService;


public void setUpTest() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    when(myService.doSomethingElse(anyString)).thenReturn(123);
}
```

Comment: @coder I had a similar class design until I came to test it when I realised my class was doing too many things making it difficult to unit test. Consider splitting the web-service work out to a handler class. This way you can construct your class with the mock'ed handler and do away with the ````@Spy````. Any calls to the ws can then be simply mocked with the traditional non-spy tooling.

Comment: That would solve the problem but the sad thing is that I cant change the original implementation of MyService or MyServiceImpl.

Comment: Ah right, yes you are correct to use a spy then. I didn't realise. They are especially useful when dealing with 3rd party/legacy code. Does my advice about the Matchers yield better mocking results?

Comment: No. The only problem I am facing here is with "@Resource" and "@InjectMocks" used on same variable. The variable gets initialised first with "@Resouce" then injection dosent happen.

Answer (score 2):

Modified,

```
    public class class1Test {

    @Mock
    private MyService myService;

    private Class1 class1;

    @Before
    public void onceBeforeEachTest() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
         this.class1 = new Class1(myService); 
        Mockito.when(myService).doSomethingElse(anyString()).thenReturn(123);
    }

    @Test
    public void methodToBeTestedTest() {
            class1.methodToBeTested();
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont have a constructor which takes an object as parameter.

Answer (score 1):

This should suits your need:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJunitRunner.class)
public class class1Test {

    @Mock
    private MyService myService;

    private Class1 class1;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        this.class1 = new Class1(myService); // creates this constructor.
    }

    @Test
    public void methodToBeTestedTest() {
        this.class1.methodToBeTested();
        Mockito.verify(this.myService).doSomethingElse(/* put expected arg here */);
    }
}
```

See also the [official doc](https://code.google.com/p/mockito/w/list).