# Why mockMVC and mockito don't work together?

Tags: spring, junit, mockito, mockmvc

I have restful services and I want to unit test them without connecting to database, therefore I have written this piece of code:

```
@Before
public void setup() throws Exception {
    this.mockMvc = webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();

    adminDao = mock(AdminDaoImpl.class);
    adminService = new AdminServiceImpl(adminDao);
}

@Test
public void getUserList_test() throws Exception {
    User user = getTestUser();
    List<User> expected = spy(Lists.newArrayList(user));

    when(adminDao.selectUserList()).thenReturn(expected);


    mockMvc.perform(get("/admin/user"))
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE))
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$", hasSize(1)))
        ;           
}
```

The service gets called but my problem is this line of code

```
when(adminDao.selectUserList()).thenReturn(expected);
```

is not working, I mean it really calls the adminDao.select method and therefore gets the result from database. which I don't want.
Do you have any idea how can I mock the method call?

Comment: They work perfectly fine together, but you are mocking classes outside of the context, how should the context know about those mocks?

Comment: @M.Deinum you are right, i know that i get webApplicationContext, but actually I cannot find a way to mock them inside the mockMVC  context. How can i fix it?

Comment: Create a configuration class which overrides the actual beans with mocks. Inject the mocks in our test class to record the behavior you want.

Comment: So you mean that I need to create a class like 
@Configuration
public class TestContext {} and then inject it like this
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestContext.class, WebAppConfig.class})
Sorry just want to make sure i am getting your real meaning.

Comment: maybe this answer will solve your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16207069/887692

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to @M. Deinum, I fixed my problem, I added a TestContext configuration file:

```
@Configuration
public class TestContext {

@Bean
public AdminDaoImpl adminDao() {
    return Mockito.mock(AdminDaoImpl.class);
}

@Bean
public AdminServiceImpl adminService() {
    return new AdminServiceImpl(adminDao());
}       
}
```

and then in my test class I annotated the class with

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestContext.class})
```

worth to mention in setUp of the test class I need to reset the mockedClass to prevent leakage:

```
@Before
public void setup() throws Exception {
    Mockito.reset(adminDaoMock);

    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
}
```

Comment: can you please post your full Test class after these changes?

Comment: This is my issue and I am a bit stuck with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58766781/mokcito-not-mocking-the-dao-layer

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating a separate TestContext class use @MockBean annotation for the same.

```
 @MockBean
 AdminDao adminDao;
```

And then use it as per your need.

```
 @Test
public void getUserList_test() throws Exception {
   User user = getTestUser();
   List<User> expected = spy(Lists.newArrayList(user));

   when(adminDao.selectUserList()).thenReturn(expected);


   mockMvc.perform(get("/admin/user"))
    .andExpect(status().isOk())
    .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE))
    .andExpect(jsonPath("$", hasSize(1)))
    ;           
}
```