# Is there a way to AutoWire WebApplicationContext in a test run by Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-mvc, junit, mockito

I have a very simple unit test:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class RestControllerTest {

    protected MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    WebApplicationContext wac;

    @InjectMocks
    protected RestController restController;

    @Mock
    protected UserService mockUserService;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);


        }
    }
```

I am stuck at figuring out how to Autowire WebApplicationContext in the above test. 
Please can somebody guide me how to do this.

P.S. I am using MockitoJUnitRunner I am not sure if this makes a difference or no. But I am new to Spring and Mockito so dont know much about either technologies.

Comment: This looks like duplicate of post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457239/injecting-mockito-mocks-into-a-spring-bean, and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19808326/how-to-inject-a-mock-in-a-spring-context

Comment: @amitmah :-) Thanks a lot. I'll go through the answer that you posted.. Appreciate the help.

Comment: @amitmah That answer is for how to get Mock objects working. My Mock objects are already working fine. I am having trouble getting the WebApplicationContext auto-wiring.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use [Spring's JUnit runner](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/junit4/SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.html) in order to be able to `@Autowire` anything.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
```

Then, you don't need to use `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` because you're already calling `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);`. You basically pick one or the other - It's shorter to use their runner, but when you can't use their runner (like in this situation), you call `initMocks()` in a `@Before` method.

Ultimately it depends on the Spring technologies you're using to decide what final steps you need to take. If you're using Spring Boot, [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html) are their docs that show you the last bits you need to get a test up and running.

Comment: No I am not using Spring Boot. And I have tried using Spring Runner but somehow it keeps failing with following error : "Failed to load Application Context" now even though I added the full path of the context it is still not able to recognize the file and says "File not Found" its so weird but then I decided to use Mockito which was working fine with Spring version 4.2.6 where i did not have to AutoWire anything. But as soon as I downgraded to Spring 4.1.9 it fails.