# mock resource in service java (mockito)

Tags: java, mockito

I am doing some tests for the class Export
I need to mock a method so I made a mockito (I am new to Mockito)

```
public Class ExportServiceImpl implements ExportService{

   @Autowired
   Service service

   public void export(){

      String exportString = service.getPath();
      domoreStuff() ....

  }
```

And

```
  public Class ServiceImpl implements Service(){

      public String getPath(){
          return "thePath";
      }
  }
```

I need to mock the getPath() method so I did in the TestNG

```
 public class ExportTestNG(){

    public textExport(){

     Service serviceMock = Mockito.mock(Service.class);
     Mockito.when(serviceMock.getData()).thenReturn("theNewPath");
     System.out.println("serviceMock.getData() : " + serviceMock.getData()); // prints "theNewPath", OK

     exportService.export();  // the getData() is not the mockito one

    }
 }
```

I may have not correclt mockito and I may not have understood how it works.
Any idea ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Injecting Mockito mocks into a Spring bean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457239/injecting-mockito-mocks-into-a-spring-bean)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wire the mock service into the exportService object.
If you have a setter for the service member variable then do this:

```
exportService.setService(serviceMock);// add this line.
exportService.export();
```

If you don't have a setter you will need to perform the wiring before calling export.
Options for this include:

- Set the value of the service member variable using reflection.
- Write a test-only version of the Service and use a test-only version of the spring configuration xml files.
- Something else (that I have never done and thus don't know about).

Comment: "Write a test-only version of the Service " NO! Then you're testing code that's never used, and not testing the code that is used. Waste of time.

Comment: a test only version of the service is to support the testing of the exportService, just like using a Mocking library.  The code being tested is not the test only version of the service but the class that is using the test only version of the service.

Comment: Ah, a mock service then. That's normally what it would be called.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Mockito to inject the mocks for you and avoid having to add setter methods.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ExportTestNG(){

    @InjectMocks
    private ExportServiceImpl exportService;

    @Mock
    private Service serviceMock;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    public textExport(){                            
        Mockito.when(serviceMock.getData()).thenReturn("theNewPath");
        exportService.export(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Adding a setter that's only used in a test is a nasty habit. :P

Comment: I need to add Autowired in addition to InjectMocks in exportService and it works !

Comment: You don't need the initMocks call, thouugh. @RunWith covers that.