# Make a fake javax.sql.DataSource?

Tags: java, spring, testing, datasource, spring-test

I have to write tests with String Test framework where many DB connections was used.

In test I don't need all *data sources* but Spring want them all to inject.

Are there any standard or well known fake **javax.sql.DataSource** implementation just to satisfy Spring DI mechanic?

Comment: The answer to this strongly depends on what the fake DataSources needs to be able to do.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Nothing to do. Just to satisfy Spring DI engine with object. No calls to `dataSource` expected.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457239/injecting-mockito-mocks-into-a-spring-bean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457239/injecting-mockito-mocks-into-a-spring-bean)

Comment: Make it a Provider<DataSource> instead then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Mockito](https://code.google.com/p/mockito/) framework.
Using [Springockito](https://bitbucket.org/kubek2k/springockito/wiki/Home) you can mock your datasources on a Spring environment.

Credit of this resource is for [kubek2k](https://stackoverflow.com/users/373671/kubek2k) in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5158409/1242531).

Comment: I afraid that `mock(JdbcTemplate.class);` can't  be used in Spring .xml config, seems I have to migrate to Java config....

Comment: I found `Springockito` is a best approach as also can fake some other parts. +1

Answer (score 5):

Using Mockito (or other mocking framwork) is preferred (as pointed out in other answers). However if you just want to make your application context up (without complaining about data source), you can use `org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource`.

You need to provide bean to the context with the name which overrides the original bean and make sure your fake bean is scanned first.

```
@Configuration
public class MyFakeConfig {

  @Bean(name = "NAME OF THE ORIGINAL BEAN TO OVERRIDE")
  public DataSource fakeDataSource() {
    return new SimpleDriverDataSource()

  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I do not know well known `DataSource` mock. You can mock it yourself using one of mock frameworks (e.g. Mockito) but IMHO better solution is to use pure java in-memory database like H2, HSQLDB or Derby. You will get real data source with real data that you can fill in test code programmatically and simulate any situation that can happen in your production code.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion! I thought about such solution but expected to find simple and non bloated solution.

Comment: It is simple. The first setup indeed will take an hour or two, but it will help you in future.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Spring's `org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDataSource` which already provides some defaults for most of the interface methods. You only need to override two.

Answer (score 0):

This is my sample which does the job:

```
<!-- Create object with mocked parts that not used. -->
<bean id="config" class="org.Config">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.mockito.Mockito" factory-method="mock">
            <constructor-arg value="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
    <property name="day" value="6"/>
</bean>
```

Update `pom.xml` with:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
  <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
  <version>1.9.5</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

It works with:

```
<spring.version>3.0.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
```