# Why this mockito does not mock

Tags: spring-mvc, mockito

This is the test class:

```
@MockBean
private UserRepository userRepository;

@Before
public void beforeClass() {
    String mobile;
    when(this.userRepository.findByMobile(Mockito.anyString())).thenAnswer(new Answer<User>() {
        @Override
        public User answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
            Object[] args = invocation.getArguments();
            return MockData.getUserByMobile((String) args[0]);
        }
    });
}

@Test
@WithUserDetails(value = MockData.CUSTOMER_USERNAME, userDetailsServiceBeanName = "customizedUserDetailsService")
public void testAdd() throws Exception {}
```

And this is the `userDetails` implementation:

```
@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

@Override
@Transactional
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) {
    User user = (User) userRepository.findByMobile(username); // user is always null
```

What I expect is when `userRepository.findByMobile` is called, it should call the `getUserByMobile` method defined in `@Before`. But obviously the `Mockito` config does not work OR `userRepository` fail to mock. What's wrong and how to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

UserRepository is used in userDetails implementation, and it needs to be injected into userDetails as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457239/injecting-mockito-mocks-into-a-spring-bean). However because XXRepository is in interface, so @InjectedMock cannot be used. Then classes become:
Test class:

```
    @MockBean
    private UserService userService;

    @InjectMocks
    private CustomizedUserDetailsService customizedUserDetailsService;

    @Before
    public void before() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        when(this.userService.findByMobile(Mockito.anyString())).thenAnswer(new Answer<User>() {
            @Override
            public User answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
                Object[] args = invocation.getArguments();
                return MockData.getUserByMobile((String) args[0]);
            }
        });
    }

    @Test
    @WithUserDetails(value = MockData.CUSTOMER_USERNAME, userDetailsServiceBeanName = "customizedUserDetailsService") {}
```

And userDetails:

```
@Autowired
private UserService userService;

@Override
@Transactional
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) {
    User user = (User) userService.findByMobile(username);
```

I can see that the userService in userDetails is the same userService mocked in test class, however `@Before` method is called after the `@WithUserDetails userDetails`. So finally in order to achieve loading MockData user been, I think I have to create another userDetails just for UT. EDIT 2: Actually, I have tried it without @InjectMocks and using userService (originally I was using userRepository), it works too.